# Allow update on specific field on specific user - Firebase Firestore Rule

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Hello I am developing an App where in there is a two type of user, first is Admin and the second one is a Regular User. Now I want to allow update on a specific field in Regular User's document called `disable`, only Admins can update this field. But another problem is that I want to allow updates in document's field only by the user itself like `if (uid == documentId) allow write in fields` since I do not want other user to just update someone's account information. How can I possibly perform this things, are they available in Rules?

Note: There will be two Collection `Admins` and `Users` where each document id is account's UID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, it is recommended that you make both `Admins` and `Users` under one collection `Users` and add a field `admin = true` for the admin's account.

And to make sure no one can update the document unless it's the same user account or an admin account, you could do that with this rule :

```
service cloud.firestore {
    function admin() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
    }
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userId} {
              allow read: if true;
              allow update, create: if admin() || (request.auth.uid == userId && !('admin' in request.writeFields));
              allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId || admin();
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps, good luck!